# ThreeJS: mesh between two ellipse curves

Tags: three.js

I am building a certain composition in three.js, with two ellipse curves on the outside (blue and red arrow).
I want to make a mesh between the two curves, and *elevate* the mesh (i.e. with a height).

Does anyone know how to do that in three.js?

This is an example of one ellipse curve:

```js
var curve = new THREE.EllipseCurve(0, 0, 25, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false, 0);
var points1 = curve.getPoints( 200 );
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points1 );
var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x666666 } );
var ellipse = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
scene.add(ellipse);
ellipse.rotation.x = Math.PI/2;
```

[image: end structure]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in several ways. I used three cylinders. Your picture shows that there is something on the top surface, a sphere and another cylinder, so I assume that these may be surfaces. You mentioned lines, you can change the red and blue cylinders to `LineBasicMaterial` and connect it to the green face, I mean cylinder. But I assume that the key for you is the material in between (in my case the green cylinder).

But if you want lines replace red and blue cylinder by these:

```
const radiusTop2 = 13;
const radiusBottom2 = 13;
const height2 = 0;
const radialSegments2 = 42;
const ellipseCurve = new THREE.EllipseCurve(
  0,
  0,
  radiusTop2,
  radiusBottom2,
  0,
  Math.PI * 2,
  false,
  0
);

const ellipsePoints = ellipseCurve.getPoints(radialSegments2);
const geometry2 = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(ellipsePoints);

const material2 = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
  color: 0x0000ff,
  linewidth: 1,
});

const cylinderBlue = new THREE.LineLoop(geometry2, material2);
cylinderBlue.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
scene.add(cylinderBlue);

const radiusTop3 = 14;
const radiusBottom3 = 14;
const height3 = 0;
const radialSegments3 = 42;
const ellipseCurveRed = new THREE.EllipseCurve(
  0,
  0,
  radiusTop3,
  radiusBottom3,
  0,
  Math.PI * 2,
  false,
  0
);

const ellipsePointsRed = ellipseCurveRed.getPoints(radialSegments3);
const geometryRed = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(ellipsePointsRed);

const materialRed = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xff0000,
  linewidth: 1,
});

const cylinderRed = new THREE.LineLoop(geometryRed, materialRed);
cylinderRed.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
scene.add(cylinderRed);
```

Keep in mind is some limitation in `linewidth`:
"*Due to limitations of the OpenGL Core Profile with the WebGL renderer on most platforms linewidth will always be 1 regardless of the set value.*"

https://threejs.org/docs/?q=linebasic#api/en/materials/LineBasicMaterial.linewidth

If you want **fat lines** you need different approach:

https://threejs.org/examples/?q=line#webgl_lines_fat

https://discourse.threejs.org/t/linebasicmaterail-changes-linewidth-on-chrome-but-not-on-firefox/43356

```html
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.159.0/build/three.module.js",
      "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.159.0/examples/jsm/"
    }
  }
</script>
<canvas class="webglHH"> </canvas>

<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "three";
  import GUI from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lil-gui@0.19.1/+esm';
  import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const sizes = {
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight,
};

const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas.webglHH");

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);
camera.position.z = -20;

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: canvas,
  antialias: true,
});
renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2));
renderer.render(scene, camera);

const radiusTop = 13;
const radiusBottom = 14;
const height = 1;
const radialSegments = 42;
const heightSegments = 1;
const openEnded = true;
const cylinderGeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(
  radiusTop,
  radiusBottom,
  height,
  radialSegments,
  heightSegments,
  openEnded
);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0x00ff00,
  wireframe: true,
});
const cylinderGreen = new THREE.Mesh(cylinderGeometry, material);
scene.add(cylinderGreen);
cylinderGreen.position.y = 0;

const radiusTop2 = 6;
const radiusBottom2 = 13;
const height2 = 1;
const radialSegments2 = 42;
const heightSegments2 = 1;
const openEnded2 = true;
const cylinderGeometry2 = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(
  radiusTop2,
  radiusBottom2,
  height2,
  radialSegments2,
  heightSegments2,
  openEnded2
);
const material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0x0000ff,
  wireframe: true,
});
const cylinderBlue = new THREE.Mesh(cylinderGeometry2, material2);
scene.add(cylinderBlue);

const radiusTop3 = 6;
const radiusBottom3 = 14;
const height3 = 1;
const radialSegments3 = 42;
const heightSegments3 = 1;
const openEnded3 = true;
const cylinderGeometry3 = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(
  radiusTop3,
  radiusBottom3,
  height3,
  radialSegments3,
  heightSegments3,
  openEnded3
);
const material3 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xff0000,
  wireframe: true,
});
const cylinderRed = new THREE.Mesh(cylinderGeometry3, material3);
scene.add(cylinderRed);

function updateCylinderHeights(newHeight) {
  const newPositionYBlue = newHeight / 2 + height2 / 2;
  const newPositionYRed = -newHeight / 2 + height3 / 2;

  cylinderBlue.position.y = newPositionYBlue;
  cylinderRed.position.y = newPositionYRed;
}

function elevator(newHeight) {
  updateCylinderHeights(newHeight);
}

const gui = new GUI()
const guiControls = {
  height: height,
};
gui.add(guiControls, "height", 1, 30).onChange(function (value) {
  cylinderGreen.scale.y = value;
  elevator(value);
});

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas);
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.enabled = true;

function onWR() {
  sizes.width = window.innerWidth;
  sizes.height = window.innerHeight;
  camera.aspect = sizes.width / sizes.height;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
window.addEventListener("resize", onWR);

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  elevator(cylinderGreen.scale.y);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();
</script>
```